# change of variables and commuting diagram for a second order differential operator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the following differential operator.

$$ \mathcal{A}: C^\infty[0,L] \to C^{\infty}[0,L] $$

given by $\mathcal{A}y = - m^{-1} g^{-1/2} (m g^{-1/2} y')' + c y$

where $m = m(x), g = g(x), c = c(x)$ for $x \in [0,L]$

Now consider the  change of variables given by the following diffeomorfisms  $Z: [0, L] \to [0, \tilde{L}]$ $X = Z^{-1}$

We would like to define an operator $\tilde{\mathcal{A}}$ that  makes the following diagram commute

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
    C^\infty[0,L] @>\mathcal{A}>> C^\infty[0,L]\\
    @A T_Z A A @VV T_X V\\
    C^\infty[0,L] @>>\tilde{\mathcal{A}}> C^\infty[0,L]
\end{CD} \qquad\quad\begin{matrix}T_X y=y\circ X\\ T_Z\tilde{y}=\tilde{y}\circ Z\end{matrix}$$

that is if we write $\tilde{y} = y \circ X$

[image]

Then we begin computations:

\begin{align}
\mathcal{A} \circ T_Z \tilde{y} = \mathcal{A} (\tilde{y} \circ Z) =  - m^{-1} g^{-1/2} (m g^{-1/2} \tilde{y}'\circ Z \cdot Z')' + c \tilde{y}\circ Z
\end{align}

Now
\begin{align}
 T_X\mathcal{A} \circ T_Z\tilde{y}  &=  - m^{-1}\circ X g^{-1/2}\circ X (m\circ X g^{-1/2}\circ X \tilde{y}'\circ Z\circ X \cdot Z'\circ X)' + c\circ X \tilde{y}\circ Z\circ X\\
&=  - m^{-1}\circ X g^{-1/2}\circ X (m\circ X g^{-1/2}\circ X \tilde{y}' \cdot Z'\circ X)' + c\circ X \tilde{y}
\end{align}
Now the claim of the book Inverse Boundary Spectral Problems pag 20 is:
(notation $Z = \tilde{X}$)
[image]
[image]

So we return to the previous calculations:

\begin{align}
 T_X\mathcal{A} \circ T_Z \tilde{y}  &=  - m^{-1}\circ X g^{-1/2}\circ X (m\circ X g^{-1/2}\circ X \tilde{y}'\circ Z\circ X \cdot Z'\circ X)' + c\circ X \tilde{y}\circ Z\circ X\\
&=  - m^{-1}\circ X g^{-1/2}\circ X (m\circ X g^{-1/2}\circ X \tilde{y}' \cdot Z'\circ X)' + c\circ X \tilde{y}\\
&=  - \tilde{m}^{-1} g^{-1/2}\circ X (\tilde{m} \tilde{g}^{-1/2}\tilde{y}' )' + \tilde{c} \tilde{y}\\
\end{align}

Since $Z \circ X = Id$ 
$$Z'\circ X = \frac{1}{X'}  $$
and 
$$\frac{1}{\tilde{g}^{1/2}}  = \frac{1}{g^{1/2}\circ X  \cdot X'} =   \frac{1}{g^{1/2}\circ X } \cdot Z'\circ X $$

I can't arrive at] the final result:
\begin{align}
 T_X\mathcal{A} \circ T_Z \tilde{y}  &=  - m^{-1}\circ X g^{-1/2}\circ X (m\circ X g^{-1/2}\circ X \tilde{y}'\circ Z\circ X \cdot Z'\circ X)' + c\circ X \tilde{y}\circ Z\circ X\\
&=  - m^{-1}\circ X g^{-1/2}\circ X (m\circ X g^{-1/2}\circ X \tilde{y}' \cdot Z'\circ X)' + c\circ X \tilde{y}\\
&=  - \tilde{m}^{-1} g^{-1/2}\circ X (\tilde{m} \tilde{g}^{-1/2}\tilde{y}' )' + \tilde{c} \tilde{y}\\
& = - \tilde{m}^{-1} \tilde{g}^{-1/2} (\tilde{m} \tilde{g}^{-1/2}\tilde{y}' )' + \tilde{c} \tilde{y}
\end{align}

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is on the following line:

Instead of

\begin{align}
 T_X\mathcal{A} \circ T_Z\tilde{y}  &=  - m^{-1}\circ X g^{-1/2}\circ X (m\circ X g^{-1/2}\circ X \tilde{y}'\circ Z\circ X \cdot Z'\circ X)' + c\circ X \tilde{y}\circ Z\circ X\\
&=  - m^{-1}\circ X g^{-1/2}\circ X (m\circ X g^{-1/2}\circ X \tilde{y}' \cdot Z'\circ X)' + c\circ X \tilde{y}
\end{align}

It should be

\begin{align}
 T_X\mathcal{A} \circ T_Z\tilde{y}  &=  - m^{-1}\circ X g^{-1/2}\circ X (m\circ X g^{-1/2}\circ X \tilde{y}'\circ Z\circ X \cdot Z'\circ X)'\frac{1}{X'} + c\circ X \tilde{y}\circ Z\circ X\\
&=  - m^{-1}\circ X g^{-1/2}\circ X (m\circ X g^{-1/2}\circ X \tilde{y}' \cdot Z'\circ X)' \frac{1}{X'} + c\circ X \tilde{y}
\end{align}

Since $T_X f' = f'\circ X  = (f \circ X)' \frac{1}{X'}$

This gives the desired result :

\begin{align}
 T_X\mathcal{A} \circ T_Z \tilde{y}  &=  - m^{-1}\circ X g^{-1/2}\circ X (m\circ X g^{-1/2}\circ X \tilde{y}'\circ Z\circ X \cdot Z'\circ X)'\frac{1}{X'} + c\circ X \tilde{y}\circ Z\circ X\\
&=  - m^{-1}\circ X g^{-1/2}\circ X (m\circ X g^{-1/2}\circ X \tilde{y}' \cdot Z'\circ X)'\frac{1}{X'} + c\circ X \tilde{y}\\
&=  - \tilde{m}^{-1} g^{-1/2}\circ X \frac{1}{X'}(\tilde{m} \tilde{g}^{-1/2}\tilde{y}' )' + \tilde{c} \tilde{y}\\
&=  - \tilde{m}^{-1} \tilde{g}^{-1/2}(\tilde{m} \tilde{g}^{-1/2}\tilde{y}' )' + \tilde{c} \tilde{y}\\
\end{align}